# Different post type as parent. URL 404 error

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I've created two different custom post types and used the link below to add a function to set post_parent. The parent is the custom post type shows and the child is the other custom post type seasons. The links to the show page works fine but we are constantly receiving 404 when trying to visit the links created for season pages.
The link structure we get for seasons is as following:
//domain/seasons/showname/season-nr/

But when disabling nice permalinks the link to the season page is only:
//domain/?seasons=season-nr/

How can we rewrite these links so that the parent name gets added as ?shows=showname and when using nice permalinks //domain/seasons/showname/season-nr/ should be possible to use.

http://janina.tumblr.com/post/3588081423/post-parent-different-type

Would really appreciate some help here, we're totally stuck at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and i solved adding a new rewrite rule just after registering the custom post type.

```
add_rewrite_rule('post-type/(.+?)/(.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$','index.php?post-type=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]','top');
```

This matches the url /post-type/parent-post/actual-post